# How can I extract the notification text in the Status Bar in lollipop version?

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

Dear all I was using the code attached below to extract the notifications text. but it didn't work in the lollipop version of android (v 5). Can you help me to fix the issue

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import de.ecspride.reactor.poc.model.Message;
import de.ecspride.reactor.poc.model.MessageParser;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class DefaultBigView implements MessageParser {
    private static final String TAG = DefaultBigView.class.getName();

    private static final int ID_FIRST_LINE = 16909023; // bigContentView

    @Override
    public Message parse(Notification notification) {
        // use simple method if bigContentView is not supported
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            return new DefaultView().parse(notification);

        Message result = new Message();

        try {
            RemoteViews views = notification.bigContentView;

            Class<?> rvClass = views.getClass();

            Field field = rvClass.getDeclaredField("mActions");
            field.setAccessible(true);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<Parcelable> actions = (ArrayList<Parcelable>) field
                    .get(views);

            for (Parcelable action : actions) {
                try {
                    // create parcel from action
                    Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
                    action.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);
                    parcel.setDataPosition(0);

                    // check if is 2 / ReflectionAction
                    int tag = parcel.readInt();
                    if (tag != 2)
                        continue;

                    int viewId = parcel.readInt();

                    String methodName = parcel.readString();
                    if (methodName == null || !methodName.equals("setText")) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "#Big Not setText: " + methodName);
                        continue;
                    }

                    // should be 10 / Character Sequence, here
                    parcel.readInt();

                    // Store the actual string
                    String value = TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR
                            .createFromParcel(parcel).toString();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Big viewId is " + viewId);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Big Found value: " + value);

                //  if (viewId == ID_FIRST_LINE) {
                        int indexDelimiter = value.indexOf(':');

                        if (indexDelimiter != -1) {
                            result.sender = value.substring(0, indexDelimiter);
                            result.message = value
                                    .substring(indexDelimiter + 2);
                        }
                //  }

                    parcel.recycle();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Big Error accessing object!", e);
                }
            }

            if (result.sender == null || result.message == null)
                return null;

            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Big Could not access mActions!", e);

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

it gives me error that there are no declared variable mActions.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the logcat.

Answer (score 3):

Android 5 Lollipop notifications are not using [RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) class directly anymore, they are now using [BuilderRemoteViews](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/app/Notification.java#Notification.BuilderRemoteViews) which extends the RemoteViews class.

You should just try to access the parent class mActions field like this

```
Field field = rvClass.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("mActions");
```